# Google Earth Web KML Not Compatible with Desktop?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I would have assumed that a KML file exported from the web version of Google Earth would work in the desktop (Pro) application. Is that not the case, or am I missing something?

I created a project on the web version, which has a Overlay pointed to a tiled XYZ source - it works fine on the web version. If I then use the "Export as KML" option and open the resulting file in the desktop app, it does not display the overlay.

Is this just not possible or is there a remedy?

Answer (score 1):

Tile Overlays are a new feature in the Google Earth web client, and are not supported in Google Earth Pro.  Both clients support the older "KML SuperOverlay" method of showing a tiled image, but only the newer web and mobile clients have the new rendering engine which also supports Tiled Overlays (using Google Maps formatted tile pyramids).